# How to use aiopg together with aiohttp

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp, aiopg

I have an application that loops through batches of URL:s from a Postgres table, downloads the URL, runs a processing function on each download and saves back the result of the processing to the table.

I have written it using aiopg and aiohttp to get it to run asynchronously.
In simplified form it looks like:

```
import asyncio
import aiopg
from aiohttp import ClientSession, TCPConnector

BATCH_SIZE = 100
dsn = "dbname=events user={} password={} host={}".format(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST)    

async def run():
    async with ClientSession(connector=TCPConnector(ssl=False, limit=100)) as session:
        async with aiopg.create_pool(dsn) as pool:
            while True:
                count = await run_batch(session, pool)
                if count == 0:
                    break

async def run_batch(session, db_pool):
    tasks = []
    async for url in get_batch(db_pool):
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(process_url(url, session, db_pool))
        tasks.append(task)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def get_batch(db_pool):
    sql = "SELECT id, url FROM db.urls ... LIMIT %s"
    async with db_pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute(sql, (BATCH_SIZE,))
            for row in cur:
                yield row

async def process_url(url, session, db_pool):
    async with session.get(url, timeout=15) as response:
        body = await response.read()
        data = process_body(body)
        await save_data(db_pool, data)

async def process_body(body):
    ...
    return data

async def save_data(db_pool, data):
    sql = "UPDATE db.urls ..."
    async with db_pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute(sql, (data,))
```

But something is wrong. The script runs slower and slower the longer it goes, also with more and more exceptions thrown from call to `session.get`. My guess is that there is something wrong with how I use the Postgres connection but I cannot figure out what's wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is the exception due to calling `save_data` instead of `save_result`?

Comment: @dirn No that was just a typo in the simplified code. I have corrected it, thanks for pointing it out!